# How to get child element that was clicked inside of a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that is loading a third part script which loads in html.

I am trying to detect when a specific part of the injected html elemen is clicked.

basically:

```
<div>
<a></a> // detect that this linked was clicked. 
</div>
```

What I have:

```
<Container onClick={(event) => {
                    event.stopPropagation();
                    const element = event.currentTarget as HTMLElement;
                    console.log('EVENT IS', element.ClassName)
}>
 // Injected thirdparty html
</Container>
```

The thing I am getting is basically the Container className butI want the source of the clicked element.

How do I do this?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you want to get the `a` element, not the `Container` component that's in the `a` tags?

Comment: The a tag is inside of the Container component. The a tag is loaded via a third-party lib. 
When I click on that a tag I want to get its className

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**event.currentTarget** is the target of the attached event. Use **event.target** to get where the event started.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget